# How in Vue.js save input to input in localstorage

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html-framework-7

I do everything for example from the official Vue.js site. But I need to use framework 7.  And in input i displayed [object InputEvent]. And when I try to write some text is also displayed [object InputEvent].

How to save a name in localstorage and display it back in input?

PS v-model in framework 7 does not work

```
  <f7-list form>
    <f7-list-input
      label="Username"
      name="username"
      placeholder="Username"
      type="text"
      v-bind:value="name"
      required validate
      pattern="[3-9a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ]+"
      @input="persist"
    />
  </f7-list>

<script>
export default {
data() {
    return{
        name: '',
        }
    },
mounted() {
  if (localStorage.name) {
    this.name = localStorage.name;
  }
},
methods: {
        persist(){
            name=$event.target.value;
        localStorage.name = this.name;

    }
}
};
</script>
```

[that's what output to input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4L3s.jpg)

Comment: There's a typo in your script script tag that you should look at as well: persist vs pArsist, but the answer should be correct

Comment: I fix it, but still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated code with proper methods of localstorage and removed a line which was cause for your issue

replace

`name=$event.target.value;`

with

```
this.name = $event.target.value;
```

Please find below updated code with updated methods and refactored code.

```
 <f7-list form>
        <f7-list-input
          label="Username"
          name="username"
          placeholder="Username"
          type="text"
          v-bind:value="name"
          required validate
          pattern="[3-9a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ]+"
          @input="persist"
        />
      </f7-list>

    <script>
    export default {
    data() {
        return{
            name: '',
            }
        },
    mounted() {
      if (localStorage.name) {
    //retrive name from localstorage here.
        this.name = localStorage.getItem('name')
      }
    },


     methods: {


                 persist(){
           /* set name to localstorage here
  using setItem is recommended  way of doing but even without that yourcode should work.*/
                    localStorage.setItem('name', $event.target.value)

            }
        }
        };
        </script>
```

Comment: Same problem with [object InputEvent].  Console error --> [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "ReferenceError: $event is not defined"

found in

---> <F7ListInput>
       <F7List>
         <F7PageContent>
           <F7Page>
             <F7View>
               <Login> at src/pages/login.vue
                 <F7View>
                   <F7App>
                     <App> at src/app.vue
                       <Root> vue.esm.js:629:7

Comment: Add this in persist and all works now  this.name = event.target.value;

Answer (score 1):

Simply :

```
localStorage.setItem('name', this.name)

this.name = localStorage.getItem('name')
```

Comment: Did I do right?  methods: {
        parsist(){
    localStorage.setItem(key, this.name);
    this.name = localStorage.getItem(key);

    }
}

Comment: @Dio those go in the separate functions

Comment: Can you please do an example how it should be.